# Multiple Variable Assignment from Single Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, loops

I'm trying to have an Array assign a value to two variables.

```
test = "hello, my,name,is,dog,how,are,you"
testsplit = test.split "," 
testsplit.each do |x,y|
  puts y
end
```

I would think that it would print

```
my
is
how
you
```

but it appears the values only get passed to `x` and not to `y`. When I run this code, `y` comes back empty.

Comment: Your title needs fixing.  There is no hash and your reference to "multiple assignment" is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array#each` will pass only one item for each iteration(thus x will be assigned a value from the array for every pass,whereas y will always be assigned to nil).Thus you need to use `Enumerable#each_slice` method with argument as 2.

```
test = "hello, my,name,is,dog,how,are,you"
testsplit = test.split "," 

testsplit.each_slice(2) do |x,y|
  puts y
end

# >>  my
# >> is
# >> how
# >> you
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to take 2 elements at a time:

```
test = "hello, my,name,is,dog,how,are,you"
testsplit = test.split "," 

testsplit.each_slice(2) do |x,y|
  puts y
end

# =>  my, is, how, you
```